# How to maximise ChromeDriver while setting up GEB/SPOCK/GROOVY Selenium tests

Tags: selenium, groovy, selenium-chromedriver, spock, geb

I am having some issues with ChromeDriver maximising when setting up my tests. The screen just doesn't get any bigger unlike FireFox driver. This is how I have it set up:

```
chrome {
        driver = {
            System.setProperty('webdriver.chrome.driver', '.....)
            def chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver()
            chromeDriver.switchTo().window(chromeDriver.getWindowHandle());
            chromeDriver.manage().window().maximize()
            chromeDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            chromeDriver
        }
```

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Since the driver was just created and only has one handle, there is no need to switchTo().

Comment: What is your chrome driver version?

Answer (score 1):

You set the size by using this command

`driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080))`
You can set to your desired dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use

```
chromeDriver.switchTo().window(chromeDriver.getWindowHandle());
```

has there will be only one window opened